# SVG straight line animation CSS

Tags: html, css, svg, svg-animate

I am trying to achieve this (the picture below) in using SVG path for animation in a website. I saw this https://css-tricks.com/svg-line-animation-works/ and wanted to try it. But i am not sure how do i create the path out and the animation. Please do help me! Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use svg code for animation. You can use CSS animation on svg paths.

```css
.st0{
fill:none;
stroke:#000000;
stroke-miterlimit:10;
stroke-dasharray: 1000;
stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
-webkit-animation: draw1 4s linear forwards;
animation: draw1 4s linear forwards;
}
.st1{
fill:none;
stroke:#000000;
stroke-miterlimit:10;
stroke-dasharray: 200;
stroke-dashoffset: 200;
-webkit-animation: draw2 3s linear 2s forwards;
animation: draw2 3s linear 2s forwards;
}
  
@-webkit-keyframes draw1{
  to {stroke-dashoffset: 0;}
}
@keyframes draw1{
  to {stroke-dashoffset: 0;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes draw2{
  to {stroke-dashoffset: 0;}
}
@keyframes draw2{
  to {stroke-dashoffset: 0;}
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  viewBox="0 0 614 53" style="enable-background:new 0 0 614 53;" xml:space="preserve">
<polyline class="st0" points="0.5,53 0.5,20.7 613.5,20.7 613.5,53 "/>
<line class="st1" x1="307" y1="53" x2="307" y2="0"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Not including the relevant part in your answer does not help.

Comment: What do you mean by not including the relevant part? Questioner finds it helpful.

Comment: Your answer only makes sense when reading the fiddle. As a coutesy to future readers, instead of linking to an external resource, the answer should be understadable here. Including the CSS in your code example would have not been much effort.

Comment: @ccprog, is it better now?

Answer (score 2):

### SVG solution

The animation uses the attribute `<stroke-dashoffset>` - the indent from the beginning of the line. At the maximum value of `<stroke-dashoffset>` the visible line is zero.
 With the value of `<stroke-dashoffset ="0">` the line acquires the maximum size.

It is necessary to accurately calculate the length of the line to avoid unpredictable effects in the animation.

In this example, the length of `<line>` is 53px,  for `<polyline>` is 680px.

```html
<style>
.st0{fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-miterlimit:10; stroke-dasharray: 680; stroke-dashoffset: 680;} 
.st1{fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-miterlimit:10; stroke-dasharray: 53; stroke-dashoffset: 53;}  
 </style>
<svg version="1.1"  viewBox="0 0 614 53" >
 <polyline class="st0" points="0.5,53 0.5,20.7 613.5,20.7 613.5,53 " >
  <animate
    attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"
    from="680"
    to="0"
    dur="2s"
    fill="freeze" />
 </polyline>
<line class="st1" x1="307" y1="53" x2="307" y2="0">
    <animate
      attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"
      from="53"
      to="0"
      dur="2s"
      fill="freeze" />
</line>
 
</svg>
```

Comment: @lel Added the second solution is `SVG`. It's not always possible to solve animation tasks only with `CSS`, as in your example.